# decoding problem with urllib2 in python

Tags: python, encoding, urllib2

I'm trying to use urllib2 in python 2.7 to fetch a page from the web. The page happens to be encoded in unicode(UTF-8) and have greek characters. When I try to fetch and print it with the code below, I get gibberish instead of the greek characters.

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen("http://www.pamestihima.gr").read()
```

The result is the same both in Netbeans 6.9.1 and in Windows 7 CLI.

I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Your Python code prints correct Greek characters to me.

Comment: Your console is not set to print Unicode (probably not set to handle UTF-8).  Search on "Python printing Unicode Characters" since that's your real problem.

Comment: print urllib2.urlopen("http://www.pamestihima.gr").read().encode("utf-8")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints correctly for me, too.

Check the character encoding of the program in which you are viewing the HTML source code. For example, in a Linux terminal, you can find "Set Character Encoding" and make sure it is UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

1. Unicode is **not** UTF-8. UTF-8 is a string encoding, like ISO-8859-1, ASCII etc.
2. Always **decode** your data as soon as possible, to make real Unicode out of it. (`'somestring in utf8'.decode('utf-8') == u'somestring in utf-8'`), unicode objects are `u''` , not `''`
3. When you have data leaving your app, always **encode** it in the proper encoding. For Web stuff this is `utf-8`mostly. For console stuff this is whatever your console encoding is. On Windows this is **not** UTF-8 by default.